# Webpack with React: is there something I am missing?

Tags: ruby, reactjs, webpack, rubygems, rack

This question will be a bit long, but I need to explain the context, so be patient, please.

I am working on an Reacj/Ruby application structured in the following way:

```
<my_app>
 |
 |_____be/
 |     
 |_____fe/
 |     |
 |     |_____node_module/
 |     |_____public/
 |     |     |_____index.html    
 |     |     |_____index.jsx
 |     |     |_____index.test.js
 |     |     |_____bundle.js
 |     |_____src/
 |           |_____app/
 |           |     |_____app.jsx
 |           |     |_____app.test.js
 |           |     |_____app.css
 |           |_____contents/
 |           |     |_____contents.jsx
 |           |     |_____contents.test.js
 |           |     |_____contents.css
 |           |_____footer/
 |           |     |_____footer.jsx
 |           |     |_____footer.test.js
 |           |     |_____footer.css
 |           |_____header/
 |           |     |_____header.jsx
 |           |     |_____header.teste.js
 |           |     |_____header.css
 |           |_____package.json
 |           |_____index.jsx
 |           |_____index.test.js
 |           |_____index.css
 |_____config.ru
 |_____Gemfile
 |_____Gemfile.lock
 |_____integrations.json
 |_____package.json
 |_____webpack.config.js
```

It is a mix of pure Ruby (no Rails, no Sinatra) and ReactJS, where **app**, **contents**, **footer** and **reader** are ReactJS components. The idea is separating completely the backend **be** from the frontend **fe**, orchestrated by webpack and Rack, where I am going to use `fetch` to grab dynamical data from tye backend.

The application, after bundled with Webpack, will be run by Rack. The `Rack::Static` middleware will deal with serving the static assets built by `npm run build` and a Ruby gem I created will redirect the calls made by de frontend to a set of POROs (Plain Old Ruby Objects) which will provide de dynamic data. It is a small framework, as you may see. A concept I am trying to prove.

When it comes to **fe**, inside it everything is fine. When I enter its directoty and do `npm test` all tests run fine, and when I run `npm start` it runs fine too.

To make things simple in this test, all the ReactJS components do is write a single word. Like this:

#### app.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './app.css';
import Header from '../header/header.jsx';
import Contents from '../contents/contents.jsx';
import Footer from '../footer/footer.jsx';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Header />
        <Contents />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And this:

#### header.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './header.css';

export default class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <p>Header</p>
    );
  }
}
```

This way, when I run `npm start` inside **fe**, all I see in my browser (at http://localhost:3000) is

```
Header
Contents
Footer
```

Well, everything fine until this point. But I need to bundle the frontend app with Webpack. This is my configuration:

#### webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'fe/src/') + '/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,'fe/public/'), 
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: './public',
        port: 3333
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

As you may see, I am creating `bundle.js` at `fe/public`. And my `Rack::Static` is configured to serve the `index.html` inside `fe/public` to all static requests, while my gem deals with the dynamical ones.

It happens that, although all modules are correctly installed and everything is bundled correctly, I see nothing when I run my app with `rackup`. No error, no problem... and no words! Just a blank browser screen.

What exactly am I missing?

**EDIT:**

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "emerald_application",
  "title": "Emerald Framework Application",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "fb": "^1.1.1",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-router": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5",
    "webpack": "^2.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run serve | npm run dev",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --port 8090"
  }
}
```

No, I haven't used `create-react-app`. But this is not a problem, because the `fe` part is running fine, i.e., the ReactJS part runs fine by itself and I know enough about ReactJS apps to create them even without `create-react-app`, specially one so small.

Comment: It might help to share your package.json, index.js and index.html. Also try adding a console log in the entry point in index.js to see if it's hit. Also, what does npm start do? Did you use create-react-app? It's not clear from your description how npm start would fire up a server at http://localhost:3000

Comment: Okay, I'll do that.

Comment: I edited the question, @skypecakes.

Comment: I think the starting point would be seeing whether the index.html is served. have you checked the page source? browser console for errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by manking some changes to the code.

First of all, I edited the `webpack.config.js`.

#### webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'fe/src/') + '/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'), // <<== THIS
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: './app',
        port: 3333
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: [ "node_modules" ],
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

As you may see, this is going to make Webpack put the `bundle.js` file in a `public` directory at the root of my app. After that I created an `index.html` file inside the same `public` directory. Pointing to an `index.html` inside `fe/src` would create a lot of trouble with the paths to images and other resources, which now will be put at `public/resources` where it will be easier to refer to them at the pages created. My `index.html` file now reads:

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

After doing this, the app wasn't still running. Webpack couldn't find the node modules installed. They were inside the `fe` dir, then I  just created a symlink with

```
$ ln -sf fe/node_modules
```

and then webpack run perfectly well and created the bundle.

This was my main goal, isolate the frontend completely inside the `fe` directory and be able at the same time to run this application from outside this dir, where I may run the complete application (backend and frontend) with a single command and under a single process. This will make the deploy easier at Heroku and other similar services.

I thank all those who took time to help me with this. This was the last step to have my web development framework running. Now it is just a matter of improving it even more.